# EF Core-Could not load assembly 'DataAccess'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'DataAccess'

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I am having an issue with EF core.

When I want to use add-migration on .Net core I receive  this error

`"Could not load assembly 'DataAccess'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'DataAccess'`.

My project has been tested on class.library and console app in .netCore.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>

{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GroupRole> GroupRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<LogDetail> LogDetails { get; set; }



    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
        @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DotNetCore;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=25423456;");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                     .HasOne(d => d.Group)
                     .WithMany(t => t.Users)
                     .HasForeignKey(d => d.GroupId)
                     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

We should migrate in x64 mode.